# Racket/ more than one function

Tags: scheme, racket

How could I address this problem?

Given a function of arity 1 and a list, return a list of applying the function to each element of the original list. For example:

```
(Mmap add1 '(1 2 3 4))                        ; -> '(2 3 4 5)
(Mmap car '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))         ; -> '(1 4 7)
(Mmap cdr '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 September 8))) ; -> '((2 3) (5 6) (8 9))
```

I've tried cond and other similar functions, but I really have little idea how to solve it.

Comment: Please clarify the output of the last call.

Comment: @leppie I'm guessing the last call is supposed to have `'(7 8 9)` as the final list element as well—I have no idea how the OP mangled that, though.

Comment: @AlexisKing  the last call, is the call and thanks for edit my post

Comment: `(define Mmap map)` will also do the trick :P

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (myfunc f alist)
  (cond
    [(empty? alist) empty]
    [else (cons (f (first alist)) (myfunc f (rest alist)))]
    ))
```

`f` is your function (e.g. add1, car) and `alist` is your argument. All you have to do is to construct a list where you apply `f` to your first argument, and append the rest of the list recursively to that.

Regarding your last example. I assume that September was defined previously as `(define September 8)`. In that case your example won't give you your desired output. The last list will contain `'September` instead of 8, because you declared your list with `'()`, which treats names as symbols.

Furthermore, the output should be `'((2 3) (5 6) (8 8))` given that `cdr` returns the second and subsequent elements of a list. So you probably want `(list 7 September 9)` as your last list in your input, so that you get `'((2 3) (5 6) (8 9))` instead.

You'd have to call the function like this: `(myfunc cdr (list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6) (list 7 September 9)))`

Edit: Obviously it would make most sense to define September as 9, as it's the ninth month of the year, and call the function like this: `(myfunc cdr (list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6) (list 7 8 September)))`

Answer (score -1):

`Mmap` can be defined in terms of `#lang racket`'s function [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=map#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29).

```
 (define Mmap map)
```